# Except for List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can I use except to list?

```
string selectedValues="1,32,33,35,36,41,45";
List<string> strLst = ///gets values
```

I want to perform like

```
strLst.Except(selectedValues);
```

**shows List does not contain defination for Except

Comment: What you have tried? what went wrong? please add more details to get better answers.  If you are looking for an option to populate `strLst` from `selectedValues` means you can use `selectedValues.Split(',').ToList();`

Comment: Use NOT with Contains : !strLst.Contains(selectedValues);

Comment: Ensure you have `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list is a list of strings like `["1", "2", "32" ...]`:

```
var listWithoutSelectedValues = strLst.Except(selectedValues.Split(',')).ToList();
```

Since `Except` is a method of LinQ, not `List<>` you need:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Let them come up with a valid question. Why do we need to assume something and guide?

Comment: I know Except is part of LINQ that's why I tag LINQ . Anyways it worked . Thank you for the solution.